# Subclass-safe class variable

Tags: python

I can do:

```
class T(object):
    i = 5

    # then use the value somewhere in a function
    def p(self):
        print id(i), T.i
```

.. but, if I happen to subclass `T` ..

```
class N(T):
    pass
```

.. then `N.i` will in fact be `T.i`. I found a way to deal with this:

```
class T(object):
    i = 5
    def p(self):
        print self.__class__.i
```

.. is this correct and sure to work? Or can it produce unexpected behavior in some situations (which I am unaware of)?

Comment: Why do you need this? What do you want to implement?

Comment: @katrielalex: that would return the **object** variable, I want the **class** variable.

Comment: @maligree: they're the same thing.

Comment: Nope. An object is an instance of a class. Pardon, this may just be me using the wrong terms, coming from a different language -- in a way. So, instance variables. Attributes? This is a case of instance attributes vs class attributes. There, I guess I got the wording right.

Comment: @maligree: Unless you specifically assign a value to the attribute as part of an instance, it'll be referencing the object held by the class anyway. http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.__class__.i` is correct and sure to work (although `i` is a poor naming choice).

if the method from which you access `i` does not use self, you can make it a class method, in which case the first parameter will be the class and not the instance:

```
class T(object):
    i = 5
    @classmethod
    def p(cls):
        print cls.i
```

To read the attribute, you can also use `self.i` safely too. But to change its value, using `self.i = value` will change the attribute of the instance, masking the class attribute for that instance.

Comment: nice answer but ugh, I really hate the word "klass".  [Most examples](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod) use "`cls`" for the first parameter to a `@classmethod`.

Answer (score 1):

Uh... did you know you can refer to class attributes from instances?

```
class T(object):
    i = 5

    def p(self):
        print(id(self.i), self.i)
```

---

Class methods aside, I just thought of an interesting idea. Why not use a property that accesses the underlying class instance?

```
class T(object):
    _i = 5

    @property
    def i(self):
        return self.__class__._i

    @i.setter(self, value)
        self.__class__._i = value
```

Of course this wouldn't prevent users from utilizing an instance's `_i` seperate from the class's `_i`.

Comment: Not if the developer that subclasses my object uses i as an object variable, therefore covering my static one. Right?

Comment: @maligree: Right, I realized that after making my post. Was away from the computer from then until just now, so I couldn't update my post until now. Actually thought of mentioning class methods, but didn't think about their use in showing the class value even with an instance attribute concealing the value on the class. You could also use a class method to modify the class attribute from an instance, or... Oh, here's an idea. See my updated answer for it.

Comment: @maligree: Using the same name for a class and instance variable should be discouraged, especially when the class variable is supposed to be overrideable in subclasses like that. With that in mind, `self.i` should be a perfectly acceptable way to access `self.__class__.i`. This isn't true only in very specific circumstances (i.e. metaclasses, in particular some of their magic members, or when `self.__class__.i` is a descriptor).